# Can the Fatespinner's Spin Fate ability be used after the target roll is made?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class

In 3.5 the Fatespinner prestige class has the ability Spin Fate: as a free action a Fatespinner can add a point or more of DC to one spell. Can this be done after the target's save roll or must it be done before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It must be done before; the description has the free action taking place during the casting of the spell. By the time the target rolls a save, the casting is complete and thus it is too late to spin it.